# Hills' mechanism for making Hypervelocity Stars

Tags: supermassive-black-hole, tidal-forces

> In Hill’s mechanism, the gravitational tidal force of
>   a single MBH disrupts an approaching binary. One star is captured on an eccentric orbit around
>   the MBH and, by conservation of energy, the other star escapes with a final velocity equal to the
>   geometric mean of the ∼$10^4$ km/s
>   infall velocity and the ∼$10^2$ km/s binary orbital velocity.
>   [Hypervelocity Stars and the Galactic Center, 
>   Warren R. Brown, p.3](https://www.cfa.harvard.edu/~wbrown/Files/hvs_review.pdf)

I don't understand how the high energy/velocity can be transferred to the star.

([Hills' 1988 Nature paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/331687a0) is still paywalled.)

Comment: Ever try throwing two rubber balls, stacked, at the ground.  If you do it right, almost all the combined energy will go into the upper ball, which will rebound to an amazing height, while the lower ball will stay near the ground.

Comment: arXiv: [The Great Escape: Discovery of a nearby 1700 km/s star ejected from the Milky Way by Sgr A*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.11725) and [MNRAS](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/advance-article-abstract/doi/10.1093/mnras/stz3081/5612212) and [Space.com](https://www.space.com/hypervelocity-star-ejected-from-milky-way.html), [carnegiescience.edu](https://carnegiescience.edu/news/runaway-star-was-ejected-heart-darkness), [livescience.com](https://www.livescience.com/star-ejected-milky-way.html) and [NYTimes](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/11/14/science/stars-black-hole-milky-way.html)

Comment: @uhoh I found an explanation in [Ejection of Hypervelocity Stars by the (Binary) Black Hole in the Galactic Center](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/379546/fulltext/58563.text.html). It looks like the same principle as the [Oberth effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberth_effect).

Comment: That's really cool! Write it up?

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks, fixed.

Comment: As I understand it, the tidal disruption of the binary system means one star can end up in a closer orbit around the MBH, and thus loses energy (more negative potential energy). The overall energy is balanced by the other star gaining a *lot* of kinetic energy.

Comment: I just noticed [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/34790/7982) and I really like it! Can I interest you in undeleting it, and if there's something that you don't like about it perhaps just editing a little bit? To sweeten the pot I've just added a bounty. Crossing 1k rep opens up new SE privileges ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Consider two unit masses with velocity $V$. Give them a small push apart so they have velocities $V+v$ and $V-v$ with $v\ll V$ . Their kinetic energies are then $$\frac{(V+v)^2}{2} \approx \frac{(V)^2}{2} +vV$$ and $$\frac{(V-v)^2}{2} \approx \frac{(V)^2}{2} -vV$$
We have transferred energy $\approx vV$ from one mass to the other with the expenditure of a much smaller  energy $v^2$.

Now suppose the masses are initially moving with some tiny velocity and then travel into a potential well where they have velocity $V$. If we push while they are in the well then one will have enough kinetic energy to escape the well plus $vV$, while the other will be trapped in the well.

This is the same principle as the [Oberth effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberth_effect), where the ejected reaction mass plays the role of one of the masses.

Comment: just fyi it's always okay to accept your own answer.